# how to achive exact, start with and like result in Apache Lucene SOLR 6.3.0

Tags: java, search, solr, autocomplete, lucene

I have started implementation for **Apache Lucene SOLR 6.3.0** for Auto complete  implementation.

In that I create column schema like :

```
<fields>  
 <field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="f" multiValued="false" />  
 <field name="specialityName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
 <field name="isActive" type="int" indexed="false" stored="true"/>  
 <field name="term" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="tableName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>     
</fields>
```

and want search in **term** column.

My requirement for auto complete result is like.

```
My data   // Exact match.
My data%  // Start with.
%My data%  // Any where in string.
```

this. So, By this I want to archive max possible result . 
I tried many ways for query but could not success.

Any help will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search as below mention way.

`prefTerm:"My Data" || prefTerm:My\ \Data* || prefTerm:*My*pain*`

```
"My Data" : Exact match

My\ \Data*: Start with, here we need to escape all extra characters which can impact in jenkins search

*My*pain*: contains search
```

Answer (score 0):

For Exact match you can try `q=term:"My data"`

For the start with you can try `q=term:My data*`

For the partial search or any where you can try `q=term:*Mydata*`

try with `q=term:My*data*`

Comment: I already tried this, but when I try with q=term:My data* it returns data for "My" only not start with "My data" and that's why I am confused.

Comment: can you try with q=term:"My*data*"...check the modified answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following field type, and when passing user input to the `SOLR` you would remove the spaces from the input itself and it will return exactly what you need:

```
        <fieldType name="input_general" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-zA-Z0-9])" replacement="" replace="all" />
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

And change `term` field to be:

```
<field name="term" type="input_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Applying your example:

For `Exact Match Search`; you can try `q=term:"Mydata"`

For `Start With Search`; you can try `q=term:Mydata*`

For `the Contain Search`; you can try `q=term:*data*`

Comment: Hi, I tried this but it generate error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameters: {replace=all} and if I remove replace="all" then it not work as expected.

Comment: I change charFilter to filter and error for replace="all" is resolved, but result is still not expected, did I miss something ?

Comment: @bharatpatel this was for solr 3.6, it's working fine even after removing replace=all, it is possible things have changed